# Confused about UTC

Tags: c, time

I am not very clear about the `time()` function.
"man 2 time" says "time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)."

My question is

- Suppose device A is in London, device B is in USA.
  Does the `time()` return same value or not?  Or does the `time()` result change with timezone?

====update====

I know my real problem. I thought UTC is a timezone. Since Wikipedia says "In some countries where English is spoken, the term Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is often used as a synonym for UTC" then I was thinking, the `time()` in USA should return (A+B). A is current USA to "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000" in USA. B is time difference of (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 USA to1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 GMT ). Seems I am totally wrong.

Comment: Have you looked into what UTC is?

Comment: yeah, it is a standard "Coordinated Universal Time
"

Comment: UTC is a universal timezone, essentially the same as GMT (Greenwich Mean Time).  Times always have an associated timezone, and in this case the documentation says it's UTC (rather than local time).  It's very clear.

Comment: `time()` always returns UTC time, so it will be the same regardless of your time zone.

Comment: @TomKarzes Strictly speaking, UTC isn't a time "zone" as it is not actually associated with any area.  That is essentially what separates UTC from GMT; GMT is an actual zone that countries use as their official time, and it also happens to align with UTC (well, that's more by design than happenstance, but who cares?)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons  I know my real problem. I thought UTC is a timezone  .since wikipedia says "In some countries where English is spoken, the term Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is often used as a synonym for UTC"   then I was thinking,  the time() in USA should return (A+B). A is current USA to  "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000" in USA. B is time difference of (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 USA to1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 GMT ). Seems I am totally wrong

Comment: um, looks like your opinion is very different from @ChristianGibbons.   if "the time expressed in UTC can be characterized as local time plus a (location- and date-specific) delta between local and UTC" is correct, then time() would return different value in different timzone.  which seems not true

Comment: "returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)" is a bit of fib.  Its not the "number of seconds", like 1,2,3,....1024,1025,1026, ... 1000000000,1000000001, 1000000002.  It is a series of _timestamps_ like `1970-1-1.0:0:0, 1970-1-1.0:0:1, 1970-1-1.0:0:2, ...`  The difference are those pesky _leap seconds_.  Unix pretends in `time_t`, they do not occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of seconds since the start of 1970 UTC doesn't vary based on where you are located in the world, so `time` returns the same regardless of where you are located in the world (assuming correct system clocks).

Conversions to local time is performed by subsequent operations.

```
$ TZ=America/Toronto perl -MPOSIX -le'
   my $time = time();
   print $time;
   print strftime("%FT%TZ", gmtime($time));
   print strftime("%FT%T%z", localtime($time)) =~ s/(?=..\z)/:/sr;
'
1552516168
2019-03-13T22:29:28Z
2019-03-13T18:29:28-04:00

$ TZ=America/Halifax perl -MPOSIX -le'
   my $time = time();
   print $time;
   print strftime("%FT%TZ", gmtime($time));
   print strftime("%FT%T%z", localtime($time)) =~ s/(?=..\z)/:/sr;
'
1552516168
2019-03-13T22:29:28Z
2019-03-13T19:29:28-03:00
```

[*Oops, I thought this question was tagged [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). However, the code should be clear enough to convey the idea to a C programmer. `time`, `gmtime`, `localtime` and `strftime` behave similarly in both languages.*]

Comment: Detail: Most conversions   `1552516168` to/from `2019-03-13T22:**:**Z` pretend _leap seconds_ do not exist, so 1552516168 is not quite the count of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00Z`.

Comment: Correct. `time()` actually returns the number of seconds that aren't leap seconds since the start of 1970 UTC.

Comment: Nice way to say it "that aren't leap seconds since the start of 1970 UTC".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your system time is set properly, the timezone in which the machine resides makes no difference as to what `time()` returns, since–as you have already acknowledged–UTC is by definition universal and does not vary from location to location.

Comment: so in USA California, can I say time() returns the number of seconds since "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 local standard"

Comment: @nathan The "+0000" part means UTC.  "local standard" doesn't mean anything.